# Munin-graph is not executing

Tags: debian, munin

I have a headless Debian box with an arm v5.
Linux NSA325 3.13.1-kirkwood-tld-2 #1 PREEMPT Tue Feb 4 03:19:07 PST 2014 armv5tel GNU/Linux

I have munin and munin-node configured on this box with apache.
Version: 2.0.6-4+deb7u2

One day I upgraded munin and the default's were to generate graphs on CGI. With such little resources available I don't really want them generated on the fly but via the old cron method, as was configured before.
I updated munin.conf setting graph_strategy cron.
restarted all the services etc and waited for graphs.
There was no graphs.
Looking in the log directory the only files updated were munin-html.log  munin-limits.log  munin-node.log  munin-update.log.
No munin-graph.log

So I executed munin-graph manually as the munin user; it generated graphs and the log.

So why is munin-graph not executing but munin-html etc is?

--Update
I ran munin-cron as the munin user and found that munin-html is outputting an error, this is stopping munin-graph.

so my question is no why is munin-html generating an issue
HTML::Template->new() : Cannot open included file partial/navigation.tmpl : file not found. at /usr/share/perl5/HTML/Template.pm line 2459.

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by extracting the .deb file manually and copying the template and static directories over the ones in /etc/munin/ for some reasons a aptitude reinstall was not copying these files?